# Installation of the plugin DEDRM in Calibre - Syntax error

Tags: syntax-error, calibre

I'm trying to install the plugin DEDRM 6.7.0 in Calibre 5.7.2 (operating system: Windows 10), but I got the following error:

calibre, version 5.7.2
ERRORE: Eccezione non gestita: **SyntaxError**:invalid syntax (calibre_plugins.dedrm.**init**, line 168)

```
calibre 5.7.2 [64bit]  embedded-python: True is64bit: True
Windows-10-10.0.19041 Windows ('64bit', 'WindowsPE')
('Windows', '10', '10.0.19041')
Python 3.8.5
Windows: ('10', '10.0.19041', '', 'Multiprocessor Free')
Interface language: it
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "calibre\gui2\preferences\plugins.py", line 317, in add_plugin
  File "calibre\customize\ui.py", line 472, in add_plugin
  File "calibre\customize\ui.py", line 61, in load_plugin
  File "calibre\customize\zipplugin.py", line 293, in load
  File "importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "calibre\customize\zipplugin.py", line 185, in exec_module
  File "calibre\customize\zipplugin.py", line 181, in get_code
  File "calibre_plugins.dedrm.__init__", line 168
    print u"{0} v{1}: Copying needed library files from plugin's zip".format(PLUGIN_NAME, PLUGIN_VERSION)
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How can I overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The plugin DEDRM 6.7.0 is not compatible with Calibre 5.7.2. It works with Calibre 4.23.0 (see [here](https://github.com/apprenticeharper/DeDRM_tools/issues/1250#issuecomment-699646142-permalink:%7E:text=DeDRM%20is%20not%20compatible%20with%20calibre%205%20yet.%20So%20you%20will%20need%20the%20previous%20version%204.23%20of%20calibre.)).